# Two nav fixed nav bars on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have two fixed nav bars one on top and other at some center of the page. When scroll reach to second nav first should hide (or become relative) &
second should become fixed bar. And when we move up the second nav now become relative (not hide) and fist one will again start showing again.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhai22/Eg4Dg/1/)

```
<div id="nav01">
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div id="nav02">
</div>
<div class="content"></div>


#nav01
{
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
#nav02
{
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
.content
{
    height: 2000px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have seen many jquery plugins but not found them useful - I am not good in scripting so need your help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()>2000){
            $("#nav02").css("position", "fixed");
            $("#nav02").css("top", 0);
            $("#nav01").hide();
        } else {
            $("#nav02").css("position", "relative");
            $("#nav01").show();
        }
    });
});
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P8Hzx/1/

Comment: How to if scroll # i.e. 2000px is unknown?

Comment: You can measure the height of the content using .height